# ¿Problema con API en nodejs?

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs, jsonobject, jsonarray

Tengo un API construida en Nodejs en la que tengo configurado un método GET y un método POST.
Al momento de enviar un Json con la siguiente estructura:

```
{"descripcion":"CAMISETA ADULTO COSTOSA","id":"770141000031","referencia":"7"}
```

No me genera ningún tipo de error y guarda los datos correctamente, pero estoy trabajando con un Json que tiene el siguiente formato.

```
{"values":[{"nameValuePairs":{"descripcion":"CAMISETA ADULTO COSTOSA","id":"770141000031","referencia":"7"}}]}
```

No están llegando los datos y aparece UNDEFINED en la base de datos.
Este es el código del POST.

```
router.post('/SincronizarDatos', (req, res) =>{


    const descripcion = req.body.descripcion;
    const ean = req.body.id;
    const referencia = req.body.referencia;


    const query = "insert into sincronizar values(" + "'" + ean + "'" + "," + "'" + referencia + "'" + ',' + "'" + descripcion + "'" + ")"
    console.log(ean);
    mysqlConnection.query(query, (err,rows) =>{

        if(!err) {
            res.json({Status: 'sincronización éxitosa'});
        }else{
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
})
module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 2):

requires instalar *body-parser*

```
npm install --save body-parser
```

agregar a express

```
var myExpress = require("express");
var myParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();
app.use( myParser.json() );  // soporte para json
app.use(myParser.urlencoded({extended : true})); // soporte para url decode.
```

ahora en tu script

```
const data = req.body.values[0].nameValuePairs
const descripcion = data.descripcion;
const ean = data.id;
const referencia = data.referencia;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ¿Qué pasa si el JSON tiene más datos? Lo intente con un for pero me genera un error.

Comment: exactamente le das un `for (x in data){  data[x].descripcion }`

Comment: Funciono perfectamente